# fetching account lookup value on case in inner query

Tags: soql, query, lookup, compile-error, childrelationship

I am fetching account lookup value in class using inner soql query but it throwing error

> Compile Error: No such column 'Account' on entity 'Case'. If you are     attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names"

```
 String con_Email = envelope.fromAddress;

    //write soql and checking sender email & existing email of contact same
    List<Contact> conList = [SELECT Id, AccountID, Block_Email__c, Email, (SELECT Account FROM cases) FROM contact WHERE email =: con_Email LIMIT 1];
```

[image]

Comment: Did you not solve this problem? It seems based on your [subsequent question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160086/assign-lookup-of-accountid-contact-value-on-case-field-compile-error-invalid-f) like this issue is resolved.

Comment: yes its resolved, sorry for forgot best answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual field API Name is `AccountId`, as you can see in the documentation for the [`Case`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_case.htm) object. So the correct sub-query would be:

```
(SELECT AccountId FROM Cases)
```

You can pull other fields *through* the `Account` reference, but you can't just pull the object itself. For example this query will compile and run just fine:

```
(SELECT Account.Name FROM Cases)
```